# Django Models Counter

Tags: python, mysql, django, counter

I am using Django with a bunch of models linked to a MySQL database.  Every so often, my project needs to generate a new number (sequentially, although this is not important) that becomes an ID for rows in one of the database tables.  I cannot use the auto-increment feature in the models because multiple rows will end up having this number (it is not the primary key).  Thus far, I have been using global variables in views.py, but every time I change anything and save, the variables are reset with the server.  What is the best way to generate a new ID like this (without it being reset all the time), preferably without writing to a file every time?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a table in your database and save those values that you want in it. Another way is to use HTTP Cookies to save values if you want to avoid server reset problem. Though, I do not prefer this way.

You can follow this link to set and read values from Cookies in django:-
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#s-setting-test-cookies